# solve this simultaneous equation: $2x + y = 5$ and $4x^2 + y^2 = 17$

Tags: systems-of-equations

I already squared both sides of the first equation: $4x^2+4xy+y^2=25$

Then minused this from the 2nd equation to get $4xy=8$

Simplified to $xy=2$

But i don't know what to do from there on out

Comment: Substitute y=5-2x in second equation and solve it for x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could instead, as suggested in [sirous](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/346566/sirous)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3580411/solve-this-simultaneous-equation-2x-y-5-and-4x2-y2-17/3580416#comment7361340_3580411), from your first equation, determine

$$2x + y = 5 \implies y = 5 - 2x \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Substitute this into your second equation to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
4x^2 + (5 - 2x)^2 & = 17 \\
4x^2 + 25 - 20x + 4x^2 & = 17 \\
8x^2 - 20x + 8 & = 0 \\
2x^2 - 5x + 2 & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Now you can use the quadratic formula to solve for the values of $x$, and then determine $y$ from \eqref{eq1A}. Also, double-check to ensure you don't have any extraneous solutions. I'll leave it to you to do those final steps.

Answer (score 3):

Now, $2x+y=5$ and $2x\cdot y=4,$ which by Viete's theorem gives:
$$(2x,y)=(4,1)$$ or $$(2x,y)=(1,4)$$ and we got an answer:
$$\left\{(2,1),\left(\frac{1}{2},4\right)\right\}$$

Answer (score 2):

So, you know $xy=2$. Notice this means $x=2/y$. (This is okay, because if $xy=2$, then $y \ne 0$.) In the first equation, then, this implies

$$2x+y = 5 \implies 2 \cdot \frac 2 y + y = \frac 4 y + y = 5$$

Multiply throughout by $y$:

$$4 + y^2 = 5y$$

You can solve this quadratic for $y$, and then you could substitute the known value to solve for $x$. (Be sure to note that you can introduce an extraneous solution in $y$ by doing this, so be sure to double-check your solution.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: put $y=5-2x$  in the second equation and solve the quadratic equation you get.

Answer (score 0):

Another neat solution is using the fact that

$$
\begin{aligned}
(2x+y)^{2}+(2x-y)^{2}&=2(4x^{2}+y^{2})\\
2x-y&=\pm 3
\end{aligned}
$$

From here it is straightforward